# Will mxDestroyArray free reallocated matrix or matrix with changed size correctly?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

Question 1:

```
mxArray *data = mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix(1, 10, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
mxSetN(data, 0);
mxDestroyArray(data);
```

Will mxDestroyArray free 10 elements or 0 elements?

Question 2:

```
mxArray *data = mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix(1, 10, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
double *ptr = mxGetPr(data);
ptr = static_cast<double*>(mxRealloc(ptr, sizeof(double) * 20));
mxSetPr(data, ptr);
mxDestroyArray(data);
```

Will mxDestroyArray free 10 elements or 20 elements?

Thank you,

Comment: please post the actual code for `mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix()`, `mxRealloc()`, `msDestroyArray()`,  and just incase it is corrupting the allocated memory pointer the code for `mxSetPr()` and `mxSetN()`.  Otherwise, how are we to know what the code is doing?

Comment: They are all existing APIs from Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Q1: At least 10 elements will be freed. [Say docs for `mxSetN`:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetn.html)

> You typically use `mxSetN` to change the shape of an existing `mxArray`. The `mxSetN`
>   function **does not allocate or deallocate** any space for the `pr`, `pi`, `ir`, or `jc`
>   arrays. So, if your calls to `mxSetN` and `mxSetM` increase the number of elements
>   in the `mxArray`, enlarge the `pr`, `pi`, `ir`, and/or `jc` arrays.

Regarding Q2:
In the [docs for `mxDestroyArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxdestroyarray.html) it specifically says that

> `mxDestroyArray` deallocates the memory occupied by the specified `mxArray` including:
>
> - Characteristics fields of the `mxArray`, such as size (m and n) and type.
> - Associated data arrays, such as `pr` and `pi` for complex arrays, and `ir` and `jc` for sparse arrays.

So it will free all `sizeof(double) * 20` bytes allocated for `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

@zeeMonkeez is correct, I just want to expand the answer a bit.

1. all 10 elements are freed
2. all 20 elements are freed

In other words, no memory leaks in either cases.

Regardless of sizes (M and N) stored in header, when the array is destroyed, think of it as [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)'ing heap allocated memory, it just knows the size of the data.

If you had returned the created arrays to MATLAB (`plhs[0] = data;`) instead of destroying them, the result is that you have wasted space, since you'd be telling MATLAB that the arrays have smaller sizes than what is actually allocated for the data (0 instead of 10 in the first case, and 10 instead of 20 in the second case). However the memory is not leaked when the arrays are destroyed. As long as the matrices are in scope in MATLAB, that extra memory is reserved but you can't access it, it will only be reclaimed when the variables are cleared/destroyed.